# How to pass param from a query to another jsp page

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have two JSP pages (display.jps and studentDisplay.jsp). The display.jsp shows a table with all the student and their grades on all of the tests taken. It also has a link on the students name to take them to the studentDisplay.jsp. I am trying to get the studentDisplay.jsp to show all of the grades of the student that has been clicked on. I have only been working with java for a week or so but I have been stomped on this for a couple of days. Im sure I'm not passing the param right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

display.jsp

```
     SELECT * from CWGrades2 ORDER BY grade DESC;
    </sql:query>


    <form>
        <table border="1" width="40%">

            <tr>

                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Grade</th>

            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">


                <tr>

                    <td><a href=“studentDisplay.jsp?${row.studentName}”>
                            <c:out value="${row.studentName}"/></a></td>
                     <td><c:out value="${row.grade}"/></td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </form>
```

studentDisplay.jsp

```
<c:set var="myVar" >
  <jsp:include page="display.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="myVar2" value="${row.studentName}"/>
  </jsp:include>
   </c:set>

  <sql:query dataSource="${dbsource}” scope="request"  var="result">

 SELECT * from CWGrades2 WHERE studentName=? <sql:param value="${myVar2}"/> ORDER BY grade DESC;
    </sql:query>

    <form>
        <table border="1" width="40%">

            <tr>

                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <th>Test</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                <tr>

                    <td><c:out value="${row.studentName}"/></td>
                     <td><c:out value="${row.grade}"/></td>
                   <td><c:out value="${row.testName}"/></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </form>


    <a href="index.jsp">Go Home</a>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

In display.jsp at below line:

```
**<a href=“studentDisplay.jsp?${row.studentName}”>**
```

You are trying to send a variable in query parameter. As far as my understanding is, query params should be sent with variable name and then value, but you are sending only value. According to me, this piece of code should be like this:

**`<a href=“studentDisplay.jsp?name=${row.studentName}”>`**

And then, in your studentDisplay.jsp you should access current studentName using "name" variable.